# Robotslegs Flow/Responsibility Diagram

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, robotlegs

a couple of month ago i saw a picture showing the responsibility of the different actors in the as3 robotlegs frameworks. The picture was great for beginners who didn't know which actor is responsible for what task. It was like: "Do you want to bind a button to an event -> use the mediator"

Does anyone remember this image/chart/flow?

It's not this one:
http://ducharme.cc/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/robotlegsDiagram.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are talking about here.

However, I would advise you to take a look at the following resources:

- https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/wiki/Best-Practices
- http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021216.do

I use these resources all the time when programming with robotlegs.

Furthermore, they have a great [support page](http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/), that features a forum and other handy resources(tutorials,code examples,extensions,..)
This would be the place to ask any robotlegs specific question.